# tower defense javascript animation

Tags: javascript, canvas

Hi :) First of all sorry for my horrible english, i'm a bad french with a bad english but i hope my resquest will be understandable.

So, i'm 17 years old and for my bac (do you know this graduate ?) Before university, i have a project for my specilisation computer science. My project is to create a Tower defense really simply in javascript/Html/Css, without graphism etc.. So my goal is to do spawn x mobs around my square, then this mobs will rush tower, if 2 mobs are on the tower, she get destroyed, if any tower left, game is lost. So, this is my code, i will ask you question after code.

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("fenetreJeu");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var mob = document.getElementById("mobile");

var fenetreDuJeuHauteur = canvas.height-5;
var fenetreDuJeuLargeur = canvas.width-5;

var largeurMobile = mob.offsetLeft;
var vx = 2; // vitesse en pixel vers la droite
var xmin = 0; // limite gauche
var xmax = fenetreDuJeuLargeur;

var hauteurMobile = mob.offsetTop; //ordonnée du mobile
var vy= 2;
var ymin = 0;
var ymax=fenetreDuJeuHauteur;

var timer1;

window.onload = function()
{

    var debut = document.getElementById("start");
    var arret   = document.getElementById("stop");
    var blocCentrale = document.getElementById("blocCentrale");
    var tour = document.getElementById("tour");


    debut.addEventListener("click",debutPartie);
    arret.addEventListener("click",pause);


    quadrillage();
    generationMob();

    ensembleMob = document.getElementsByClassName("monstre");
    ensembleMob[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";



}
function generationMob()
{
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    creationPositionnement();
    }
}

function creationPositionnement(){

    var ensembleMob = [];
    var mobCree = document.createElement("div");

        mobCree.className = "monstre";
        mobCree.style.width = "5px";
        mobCree.style.height = "5px";
        mobCree.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        mobCree.style.position = "absolute";
        ensembleMob = document.getElementsByClassName("monstre");


    var mobCreeHauteur = mobCree.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*595)+"px";
    var mobCreeLargeur = mobCree.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random()*595)+"px";
    var aleatoirePosition = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);

    if (aleatoirePosition == 1){
        if (mobCreeHauteur != 0){
            mobCree.style.left = "0"+"px";}
    }if (aleatoirePosition == 2){
        if (mobCreeLargeur != 0){
            mobCree.style.top = "0"+"px";}
    }if (aleatoirePosition == 3){
        if (mobCreeHauteur != 0){
            mobCree.style.left = "595"+"px";}
    }if (aleatoirePosition == 4){
        if (mobCreeLargeur != 0){
            mobCree.style.top = "595"+"px";}
    }
    blocCentrale.appendChild(mobCree);

    return ensembleMob;
}

function positionCurseur ()
{


}

function quadrillage (){
    var larg = 50;
    var haut = 50;

    for (var i = 0; i < 40;i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(larg,0); 
        ctx.lineTo(larg,600);
        ctx.stroke();
        larg +=50;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 20;i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0,haut); 
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width,haut);
        ctx.stroke();
        haut +=50;
    }
}

function debutPartie(){
    // lance le changement de position tout les 0,01 secondes.
    clearInterval(timer1); //arrête un éventuel timer déjà en place.
    timer1 = setInterval(animation2,10); // Lance le déplacement
}


function pause(){
    clearInterval(timer1);
}

var animation = function() {
    // déplace le mobile de Vx pixels vers la droite et change Vx si on arrive au bord.
    largeurMobile = largeurMobile + Vx;    
    if ((largeurMobile<=xmin) || (largeurMobile>=xmax)) {
        Vx=-Vx; // Si on est au bord, on change le sens de déplacement.
    }
    mobile.style.left=largeurMobile+"px"; // déplacement de l'objet à l'écran.

    hauteurMobile = hauteurMobile + Vy;    
    if ((hauteurMobile<=ymin) || (hauteurMobile>=ymax)) {
        Vy=-Vy; // Si on est au bord, on change le sens de déplacement.
    }
    mobile.style.top=hauteurMobile+"px"; // déplacement de l'objet à l'écran.
}

function animationBis(){

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        ensembleMob[i].style.left = ensembleMob[i].offsetLeft + vy + "px";
        if (ensembleMob[i].offsetLeft <= 0 || ensembleMob[i].offsetLeft >= 595){
        vx =- vx;
        }


        ensembleMob[i].style.top = ensembleMob[i].offsetTop + vx + "px";
        if (ensembleMob[i].offsetTop <= 0 || ensembleMob[i].offsetTop >= 595){
        vy =- vy;
        }

    }
}

function animation2(){


        ensembleMob[0].style.left = ensembleMob[0].offsetLeft + vy + "px";
            if (ensembleMob[0].offsetLeft <= 0 || ensembleMob[0].offsetLeft >= 595){
            vy =- vy;
            }
        ensembleMob[0].style.top = ensembleMob[0].offsetTop + vx + "px";
            if (ensembleMob[0].offsetTop <= 0 || ensembleMob[0].offsetTop >= 595){
            vx =- vx;
            }


}

// calculer la position d'un element sur la page 
/*calcul la position d'un élément sur la page

            var item = document.getElementById(img);
            var parent = item.offsetParent;
            var posElmX = 0;
            var posElmY = 0;
            while(parent) {
                posElmX += parent.offsetLeft;
                posElmY += parent.offsetTop;
                parent = parent.offsetParent;
            }
            var positionX = item.offsetLeft + posElmX;
            var positionY = item.offsetTop + posElmY;



changer les dimension d'un élément

            item.style.width = item.offsetWidth+10+'px';
                        item.style.height = item.offsetHeight+5+'px';
                        */
```

Don't take care about somes function, example: function animation was a test, animationBis doesn't work, but animation2 work except if div is at the bottom or right to the block central.

So my question is about animationBis it's a "test" but i think i need ideas of this function later for the finally animation, it doesn't work. Div(mob) move yeah, but really strange move, like they are in a other div but not on my block central. I think it's because of my var vitesse, but i'm not sure.

Another question if i can :)
How can i say at mob "U rush the tower (automatic move from him position to the tower)" ?

As you see, my level of javascript is really bad and i only use function so if u can give me a answer with function i prefer :)

Still and still sorry for my awful english and thx for your answers and your patience to read me. Bye :)

Comment: You question is very unclear in both language and meaning. Please ask for facts rather than ideas. Stackoverflow is supposed to provide answers to repeatedly occourring problems. If you need help for how to set up your basic structure, it's best to find someone that can accompany you with the project. The problem is where to find such people.  It would really help if you could put this into a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net), so we could look at it directly.

Comment: so basically, you want us to get you into univ?

Comment: Nah but i don't know if u know the term "bac" in english ? It's a graduate at the end of the obligatory school. And in this "bac", a catagory choose between math, etc it call "isn but" with only 2 hours by week, teachers don't give a really lesson but only tips. I will try to use jsfiddle.net

Comment: Well i'm french, and i might state for all that we don't care about french education system. Just bee clear about your goals, current status, and issue(s), and create a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example of using two very handy techniques:

```
// Define state variables like so:
var MOVING_LEFT = 1;
var MOVING_RIGHT = 2;
var MOVING_UP = 3;
var MOVING_DOWN = 4;

// Use these human-readable variable names to set states
var current_moving_direction = MOVING_RIGHT;

// Use these variables to check for the state again
switch (current_moving_direction){
    case MOVING_LEFT:
    // Execute code for moving left
    break;
    case MOVING_RIGHT:
    // Execute code for moving right
    break;
    case MOVING_UP:
    // Execute code for moving up
    break;
    case MOVING_DOWN:
    // Execute code for moving down
    break;
}
```

The variables in upper-case letters are contants. They contain the numbers 1-4 that you had to manage yourself in your way of doing it. That way, what you see from these numbers is just what they mean. Still, you can check for the numbers that are now stored in them.

The switch-case statement checks the variable 'current_moving_direction' for all states defined by each 'case' label. The 'break' is necessary to break the switch-case, once a condition was true.